# Deleting top N records in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I can't believe I can't find how to do this, but I'm having trouble deleting the top 20 records in Rails 4.

I'm trying variations of this:

```
Comment.all(:order=> 'id asc', :limit => 20).delete
```

or

```
Comment.find(:all, :order => 'id asc', :limit => 20).delete
```

I'm getting this error:

> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`destroy_all`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/destroy_all)

```
Comment.order('id').limit(20).destroy_all
```

Comment: Upvoted this answer because you *really* should specify the sort direction in your order clause, especially when deleting records.

Comment: @JeffPerrin:   _OP_ is trying to sort records in the ascending order, not descending. Moreover, `asc` is the default rule for `order by` clause, so it is kinda superfluous to explicitly set it – only in case when you want to sort by multiple columns with different order directions.